# zend framewrork 2 and database operations with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework2

i am already working on the zend framework 2 and looking to working with MongoDB, where can i start with.there is very little in zend documentation.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.save-handler.mongo-db.html

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is going with Doctrine. There is a module for zf2: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule

Comment: I am working with rest api, is it make sense to work on these

Comment: It is your model nothing to do if it is an API or not. The model is independent of your controllers.